# Extending Selenium: how to use XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm writing an extension for Selenium that looks something like this:

```
Selenium.prototype.getStuff = function(locator) {
    ...my code...
}
```

in the "my code" section, I want to use an XmlHttpRequest. How would I go about this? The method signature in this case does not contain a callback, so I'm not sure how I would be able to wait for the server response.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Questions requesting code are not on-topic here. It is expected that you do some research, try some code, and then if things don't work you ask a specific question, post the code you tried, any error messages and any other related info to help us answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

So, one of the fast not good idea is using the locator as a container. For

example, you can pass:

```
{
    'locator' : 'locator',
    'callback': function(){}
}
```

In other way you can pass the callback, and use arguments in your getStuff function to find out not declared arguments.